# Tutorial for creation of packet in Linux kernel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand the journey a piece of data undergoes through the linux kernel from application layer onto the wire in detail through the kernel.  Does anyone know of a good place to start or a good tutorial?

Comment: Are you asking about the TCP/IP stack?

Answer (score 3):

The book "Understanding the Linux Kernel" definitely has some answers for you

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know, but the big picture is something like this:

First thing:
Application -> Kernel  (trough the socket, resulted from binding to a port)

Inside the Kernel:
NetFilter <=> TCP/IP Stack -> NIC's driver

After the kernel:
NIC's Firmware -> Wire

Links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Architecture

Later: After a bit of googling, look at what I've found:

- http://www.ecsl.cs.sunysb.edu/elibrary/linux/network/LinuxKernel.pdf (it's a bit old this document, as it seems to describe the 2.4 kernel but may be helpful)
- http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/  (has some interesting links)
- http://www.linuxhq.com/lkprogram.html#networking

Answer (score 2):

The best online references are

- [Net:Kernel Flow](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Net:Kernel_Flow)
- [Anatomy of the Linux networking stack](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-networking-stack/)

but if you are looking for a more in depth dead-tree reference, I'd recommend [Understanding Linux Network Internals](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002558)